# Why isn't my selenium working in python script?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having some issues with selenium in my python script.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path/to/chromedriver)
```

After executing the script the terminal is just outputting :

> `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

the problem is in third line

> `browser = webdriver.Chrome(path/to/chromedriver)`

and I don't really know what to do.
I'm pretty sure that the chrome driver path is correct tho.

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Are you literally typing `path/to/chromedriver`, without quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the `webdriver_manager`, as it will take care of downloading the latest stable driver based on the browser version and also takes care of the execution paths.

Use the below 3 simple lines to start the chrome driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager``

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()
```

Make sure you have `selenium` and `webdriver_manager` libraries added to the project.

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this/any answer is/was helpful to you. Also [Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) for the benefit of the future readers

Answer (score 1):

*Should be, assuming you are on windows*

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
```

*Or*

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")
```

*Webdriver download*

*https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads*

*You can also download and install the [chromedriver binary](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-binary/)*

*Just import `chromedriver_binary`. This will add the executable to your PATH so it will be found.*

*You can also get the absolute filename of the binary with `chromedriver_binary.chromedriver_filename.`*

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary  # Adds chromedriver binary to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

You have to put the path as a string in quotes `"<path to chromdriver>"` and would have to use `r` (for raw) before the string if it only includes single `\` e.g. `r"C:\Users\user\..."` else you don't need it if you path is like `"C:\\Users\\user..."`.

Do:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"<path to chromedriver>")
```

where "path to chromedriver" is the path to the chromedriver e.g. `"C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"`.